# How to start a link when entering page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have this link on my web page:

```html
<a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03</a>
```

How can I make that link run automatically, when I enter my page?

Hope you can help me!

Thanks :-)

Comment: What do you mean with 'run'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a id="demo03" href="#modal-03">DEMO03</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var link = document.getElementById('demo03');
                link.click();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about the modal-03?

Comment: This code will trigger a click event on the link. Then the link will work as we do the click manually.

Comment: How do I add these codes to my html file? Is it just putting them in <script> tags in the header, both of them?

Comment: inside the script tag before body close(</body>). And use the second code(using javascript)

Comment: So the first code, I put before the closing body tag, and how do I add the second code using javascript?

Comment: Don't include the first code. If you want to use the first code then you have to include jquery file. You have to use any one of both.

Comment: I added the javascript one, but it doesn't work.

There are two elements in the link to worry about
id = demo03 and href = modal-03
So I think they need to be included in the automatic link clicking code?